# delay the effects of ondragover in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade divs in as I drag over them by 10% at a slow rate. however, it is just going black instantly, with some faded squares if I move the mouse super fast.

Q: How do I make the square fade slowly towards black by 10% but be able to stop when the user is no longer dragging the mouse.

Thanks in advance, I've tried techniques such as the .delay function with no success.

```js
(function() {    
    
    //When the mouse drags over the class cell, lower the opacity by 10%
    $('.cell').on('dragover', function () {
        var $currentOpacity = $(this).css("opacity");
        $currentOpacity -= 0.1;
        $(this).css('opacity', $currentOpacity);
    });
    
    
})();
```

```css
#grid-container {
    width: 398px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

.cell {
    margin: 0.5px;
    height: 5mm;
    width: 5mm;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block; 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
     <div id="grid-container">
        <div class="row line-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
(function() {    

    //When the mouse drags over the class cell, lower the opacity by 10%
    $('.cell').on('dragover', function () {
        var $currentOpacity = $(this).css("opacity");
        $currentOpacity -= 0.1;
        var $element = $(this);
        //prevent reset
        clearTimeout($element.resetEvent)
        //update opacity
        $element.css('opacity', $currentOpacity);
        //trigger reset after 2 seconds
        $element.resetEvent = setTimeout(function(){
            $element.css('opacity', 1);
        }, 2000);
    });


})();
```

If there is ever 2 seconds of inactivity, the opacity returns to 1. However if `dragover` is triggered, it prevents the reset and starts the clock over again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using **CSS transitions**. Add transition for `"background-color"` to your class and change the `"background-color"` of element on `dragover` event using new class.

```js
(function() {    
    
    //When the mouse drags over the class cell, lower the opacity by 10%
    $('.cell').on('dragover', function () {
       /* instead of calculation, only add class to element. */
        $(this).addClass("dragged");
    });
    
    
})();
```

```css
#grid-container {
    width: 398px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

.cell {
    margin: 0.5px;
    height: 5mm;
    width: 5mm;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block; 
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.dragged {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
     <div id="grid-container">
        <div class="row line-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```